# Return particular sheet from Workbook in byte[]

Tags: excel, apache-poi, hssfworkbook

I have this excel workbook stored in my resources folder.  Considering this excel is of 9 pages i want to extract a particular page and return it into from of byte[].

I created this controller

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getSinglePage/{pageNumber}")
    private ResponseEntity<byte[]> getExcelByPageNumber(@PathVariable Integer pageNumber) throws IOException {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.getExcelByPageNumber(pageNumber), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

The service code contains--

```
public byte[] getExcelByPageNumber(Integer pageNumber) throws IOException {
        
        Workbook workbook = null;
        byte[] byteArray = null;
        // here file.xls is my excel sheet that contains 9 sheet for example

        workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(loader.getResource("classpath:file.xls").getInputStream());
        //gets the sheet from given page number 
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(pageNumber);
    
        // now i want to return this sheet in the form of byte[]
        return byteArray;
    }
```

How should I return it into form of byte[]?

Comment: Not possible. A worksheet cannot exist without its workbook. What one could do is opening the workbook, removing all not needed sheets and writing the workbook into another file or into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to get it as `byte[]`.

Comment: What data are you trying to return? Maybe just extract the contents of the cells and return that as JSON?

Comment: How can I write data of a single worksheet into ByteArrayOutputStream - @Axel. kindly help with a code snippet.

Comment: I want to return a single worksheet from a workbook in the form of byte[] - @Gagravarr

Comment: What are you then going to do with those bytes? What do you think they will contain? What are you then going to pass them to?

Comment: I would rather like to download that particular worksheet.@Gagravarr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing some POC I get to know a single worksheet could not exist without having its own workbook. And Workbook has restricted libraries to work on. So apparently I could not find any direct solution to copy or append the sheet.

What i did is I removed the sheets which are not needed that is keeping only sheet in the workbook and then writing it using ByteArrayOutputStream.

```
 public byte[] getExcelByPageNumber(Integer pageNumber) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(loader.getResource("classpath:file.xls").getInputStream());
        Sheet tmpSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(pageNumber - 1);
        for (int i = workbook.getNumberOfSheets() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            String sheetName = workbook.getSheetName(i).trim();

            if (!tmpSheet.getSheetName().equals(sheetName)) {
                workbook.removeSheetAt(i);
            }

        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            workbook.write(bos);
        } finally {
            bos.close();
        }
        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        return bytes;

    }
```